# #R - FOR loop - how to loop through every element of a vector in a column of a data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop

The goals is to create a vector indicating if the student was absent(1), present(0), or if the data was missing(NA)

```
Present <- data$attendancecode
attendance <- c()

for (i in seq_along(Present)){
  if (is.na(i)==TRUE) {
    attendance [i] <- NA
  } else if (grepl("A|G|X|Z", i)){
    attendance [i] <- 1
  } else {attendance [i] <- 0}
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working...

Comment: Welcome Welcome. Have a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In short: Please give us some data to play with.

Comment: please provide a small data sample if possible, so your problem gets more reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: give us some data to work with

Answer (score 2):

`seq_along` will give you a vector of indices, i.e. `1:length(Present)`. So your `is.na` call will always return false. Instead do

```
for (i in seq_along(Present)){
  if (is.na(present[i])) { # don't need == TRUE, is.na returns TRUE or FALSE
    attendance [i] <- NA
  } else if (grepl("A|G|X|Z", i)){
    attendance [i] <- 1
  } else {Present [i] <- 0} # not sure what you intend to do here... do you mean to overwrite the value in Present? or do you mean to assign to attendance?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The goal for the last else is to assign attendance.  There are 6 other letters that all should equate to 0.

Comment: @Jasmine nice for-loop practice - now the cool thing about R is to vectorise your if else statement. Your code will be shorter, more understandable and faster :)

Comment: Does it matter that Present is a vector of characters and not values? I got an error message that said In is.na(attendance[i]) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: @Tjebo I took a look at the "How to include NA in ifelse", but they were only including NA as one of the two options....I have three options which would be NA, 1, or 0. Still kind of helpful, but doesn't exactly solve my code problem...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your last line, you make an assignment in `Present` when you mean to in `attendance`. But I think @mikeck gets the real issue.

That said, if you're OK with not using a for loop:

```
Present <- c("A", "G", "Z", "Q", "Q", NA, NA)

attendance <- purrr::map_dbl(Present, ~case_when(
  is.na(.x) ~ NA_real_,
  grepl("A|G|X|Z", .x) ~ 1,
  TRUE ~ 0
))

> attendance
[1]  1  1  1  0  0 NA NA
```